# how to get firebase database in android studio

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in android studio,
i have trouble retrieving the vehicle class in my firebase database. would like to get the data according to date, then plateno. and store each entry in an array. i have tried most solutions found here but as a noob, i have difficulty in condensing the solutions. thanks for your help:
here's my database structure:

[image]

here is my code:

```
public void getDatabase() {
     FirebaseDatabase myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     DatabaseReference ref = myRef.getReference();
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               for(DataSnapshot onemarker: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        key =onemarker.getKey();
                        myvehicle = onemarker.child(key).child("OneMarker").getValue(Vehicle.class);
                        String stats = myvehicle.status;
                        vehiclearray.add(myvehicle);

                  new AlertDialog.Builder(MonitorActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Vehicle Information")
                            .setMessage("  "+stats+" "+key+"  "+vehiclearray.size())
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(R.mipmap.inmissionmarker)
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,null)
                            .show();

                }
            }
```

when ran, the app stopped and closes.
here's the error code:

```
12-11 08:49:27.336 1272-1272/? D/Settings: Mon Dec 11 08:49:27 GMT+08:00 2017 , device_provisioned : 1
                                       java.lang.RuntimeException
                                           at android.provider.Settings$LogMsg.writeCallStackLog(Settings.java:1085)
                                           at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1206)
                                           at android.provider.Settings$Global.putStringForUser(Settings.java:12282)
                                           at android.provider.Settings$Secure.putStringForUser(Settings.java:7421)
                                           at android.provider.Settings$Secure.putIntForUser(Settings.java:7533)
                                           at android.provider.Settings$Secure.putInt(Settings.java:7527)
                                           at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:529)
                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3104)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735)
                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: the alert dialog is just to verify if the data has been retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you can actually get rid of *onemarker*. You don't need another key there. It can be directly parsed with the POJO class.

> onemarker.getValue(Vehicle.class); //onemarker is the snapshot

Could you please add logs for crash (i.e., app close)

Comment: thank you for your reply. the app ran without error. but the result in the dialog is: null --L-nZBi2qM6jUwlkuWoZ 6. the current size of the database is 6, i assume that it is copied to the array, and the last key is correct too. there is no value (even of the last database entry) for the string stats. will try to check on the arraylist. there is no log for the crash this time.

Comment: One more observation is, the alertdialog can be moved out of the _for_ loop. One more important to remember is **Keys in firebase and in your POJO should match**

Comment: yes. the alert dialog is for checking if the database is retrieved. the only retrieved data is the key and the array size. the myvehicle class returned empty.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ValueEventListener markerListener = (new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            vehiclearray.clear();
            int counter=0;
            for (DataSnapshot onemarker : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                myvehicle = onemarker.getValue(Vehicle.class);
                vehiclearray.add(myvehicle);
                tvVehicle1.setText(vehiclearray.get(counter).plateno);
                counter++;
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MonitorActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Vehicle Information")
                    .setMessage(counter+ "  entries found on database ")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.mipmap.inmissionmarker)
                    .show();
        }
```